# After entering password Mac shuts down

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, login

I am using **MacBook Air 13"** with **macOS Sierra**.

I am facing with this problem for the first time, never had any issues with my MacBook before for almost 3 years.

I turned on my MacBook, picked my user, entered password and progress bar started loading, it filled for about 3/4 and laptop shut down. This happens every time I try to login into my user. However, I am able to login as a ***Guest***.

I turned it on with `Cmd + S` buttons and saw a message :
`BuildError(): error building a user of type 0x20010008`

**Question:**
I am hoping this is not a ***hardware issue***. If it is a ***software issue*** I have no problems reinstalling my macOS, but how do I save all my data/files that I have? (I am not using TimeMachine)

Comment: Have you tried to just reinstalling macOS.

Comment: @IronCraftMan I can do it, but the best case for me would be to copy all the data from my hard drive or to be able to save it, and then reinstall macOS

Comment: reinstalling won't make you loose all your data. It's just like updating the system, instead you're installing the same update. You'd need to go into disk utility to actually erase all your data.

Comment: @Blank I had an issue with none of my dictation commands working on Sierra.  Apple tech support suggested to reinstall Sierra.  I did what they suggested and the reinstallation left all of my files in tact.  It just reinstalled all the operating system files. There was no need to copy my data from the hard drive. I wasn't too concerned about it anyway because I have Time Machine backups

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, so after some searching/googling I found that all problems that I had was because of **FileVault bug that makes your OS pause/freeze at login**.

This FileVault bug first was seen on **Mac OS X Yosemite**, I do not know why I faced with this issue on **macOS Sierra**, which must work perfectly, but nvm, here is my solution.

---

## Solutions

*(Works if your FileVault is turned ON, if not, it may be hardware issue)*

When you supply a password for your account at login screen your OS starts to unlock the disk. Unfortunately in some cases this process seems to be hindered by some bug with FileVault 2 setups that prevents their systems from immediately unlocking and loading the OS, so their systems now take up to several minutes to log in, or fail to log in as in my case.

#### Solution 1 - If your OS loads for a long time

Ensure you have a **full backup** of your Mac using Time Machine.

- Go to `FileVault` tab in the `Security & Privacy` system preferences and turn off FileVault.
- When FileVault is disabled and your drive is decrypted, restart your Mac.
- Hold the <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> keys down at the boot chimes to load your Mac into Recovery Mode.
- Open `Disk Utility` and use it to run a `Repair Disk` routine, available in the `First Aid` tab when you select your hard drive. Do this for both the hard drive device, and your boot volume.
- Restart your Mac normally and log in.
- Re-enable `FileVault` in the `Security & Privacy` system preferences.

#### Solution 2 - If you can't login and stuck watching progress bar loading forever

The above routine works for if you can eventually boot your Mac in the face of this bug, but if you cannot log in and see the system hang on the loading progress bar for hours with no ability to use your system, then you will have to use another procedure:

- Reboot your system and hold the <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> keys at the startup chimes to load into `Recovery Mode`.
- Use `Disk Utility` to turn off encryption on your boot drive. If this gives you errors, then reboot in `Target Disk Mode` (hold the <kbd>T</kbd> key at the boot chimes) and use `Disk Utility` on another Mac via a **Thunderbolt** or **Firewire cable** to turn off encryption. Alternatively, you can try booting to `Internet Recovery` by holding <kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> at the boot chimes, which will avoid using your internal drive for any boot purposes.
- With your drive unlocked and decrypted, use `Disk Utility` to verify and repair your boot drive.
- Restart your Mac normally.
- Use the `Security & Privacy` system preferences to re-enable `FileVault`.

Comment: I really hope this will help someone, so no one will stuck as I did. And **always** have backup of your system, it can save you a lot of time.

Comment: Seems this solved my problem. Cost my half a day. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you for saving my day and frustration.

Answer (score 0):

I found UserNotFoundException's answer useful, however, what worked for me was to **disable** the "**Reopen windows when logging back in**" checkbox on the **Restart window**.

Seems like something was stored there that was shutting off my Macbook every time I tried to log in without Safe Mode. Weird.

I had also tried [removing the login items](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25614?locale=en_US) previously to no avail.